# Is it possible to explicitly set order the stacks in a matplotlib stackplot?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, matplotlib

I want to explicitly set the order of the stacks in a Matplotlib stackplot.  Here is an example:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
%matplotlib inline

np.random.seed(1)
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,100,size=(100,4)),columns=list('ABCD'))

df.plot(kind='area',stacked=True,figsize=(20,10));
```

This produces the following image:

[image]

The last row of the dataframe from:

```
df.tail(1)
```

is:

```
    A   B   C   D
99  16  30  84  57
```

Here is what I want to achieve:

I want to re-order the plot of the stacks such that the stacks are plotted from the bottom up A, B, D, C i.e. the columns ordered from the bottom up, by the order of their increasing values in the last row of the df.

So far, I have tried re-ordering explicitly the columns in the df before plotting:

```
df[['A','B','D','C']].plot(kind='area',stacked=True,figsize=(20,10))
```

but this produces exactly the same chart as above.

Thank you for any help here!

Comment: Actually it didn't create the same plot. The colors or the same but shapes under the red chart are different.  Look closely.

Comment: Aye, aye, aye. I was creating an example from an existing issue.  It seems you are right on this, but let me go back to the original and check again.  Thanks so far!...

Comment: Ahhh.  Even for this, this was the case.  So re-ordering is that simple!  Thank you for noticing the detail!  I guess we leave the question here, in case anyone needs that specific knowledge!  Thanks again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The graphs are not the same.  Look at the areas beneath the red graph for a particle x. The shapes for those graphs are different for the green and blue shaded areas.

[image]

And now,

```
df[['A','B','D','C']].plot(kind='area',stacked=True,figsize=(20,10))
```

[image]